# Boost Ping Example

Tags: c++, loops, boost, ping

I used to know more in C++ thanks to Boost, and I have two questions.
First : in Object Oriented Programmation, what the ":" stand for ? I mean that :

```
pinger(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, const char* destination)
    : resolver_(io_service), socket_(io_service, icmp::v4()),
    timer_(io_service), sequence_number_(0), num_replies_()
```

This code is in the boost ICMP exemple.
My second question is, why do this code continue infinitely ?

```
class pinger
{
    public:
        pinger(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, const char* destination)
        : resolver_(io_service), socket_(io_service, icmp::v4()),
        timer_(io_service), sequence_number_(0), num_replies_(0)
        {
            icmp::resolver::query query(icmp::v4(), destination, "");
            destination_ = *resolver_.resolve(query);
            start_send();
            start_receive();
        }

    private:
        void start_send()
        {
            std::string body("\"Hello!\" from Asio ping.");
            // Create an ICMP header for an echo request.
            icmp_header echo_request;
            echo_request.type(icmp_header::echo_request);
            echo_request.code(0);
            echo_request.identifier(get_identifier());
            echo_request.sequence_number(++sequence_number_);
            compute_checksum(echo_request, body.begin(), body.end());
            // Encode the request packet.
            boost::asio::streambuf request_buffer;
            std::ostream os(&request_buffer);
            os << echo_request << body;
            // Send the request.
            time_sent_ = posix_time::microsec_clock::universal_time();
            socket_.send_to(request_buffer.data(), destination_);
            // Wait up to five seconds for a reply.
            num_replies_ = 0;
            timer_.expires_at(time_sent_ + posix_time::seconds(5));
            timer_.async_wait(boost::bind(&pinger::handle_timeout, this));
        }

        void handle_timeout()
        {
            if (num_replies_ == 0)
            std::cout << "Request timed out" << std::endl;

            // Requests must be sent no less than one second apart.
            timer_.expires_at(time_sent_ + posix_time::seconds(1));
            timer_.async_wait(boost::bind(&pinger::start_send, this));
        }

        void start_receive()
        {
            // Discard any data already in the buffer.
            reply_buffer_.consume(reply_buffer_.size());

            // Wait for a reply. We prepare the buffer to receive up to 64KB.
            socket_.async_receive(reply_buffer_.prepare(65536),
            boost::bind(&pinger::handle_receive, this, _2));
        }

        void handle_receive(std::size_t length)
        {
            // The actual number of bytes received is committed to the buffer so that we
            // can extract it using a std::istream object.
            reply_buffer_.commit(length);

            // Decode the reply packet.
            std::istream is(&reply_buffer_);
            ipv4_header ipv4_hdr;
            icmp_header icmp_hdr;
            is >> ipv4_hdr >> icmp_hdr;

            // We can receive all ICMP packets received by the host, so we need to
            // filter out only the echo replies that match the our identifier and
            // expected sequence number.
            if (is && icmp_hdr.type() == icmp_header::echo_reply
            && icmp_hdr.identifier() == get_identifier()
            && icmp_hdr.sequence_number() == sequence_number_)
            {
                // If this is the first reply, interrupt the five second timeout.
                if (num_replies_++ == 0)
                    timer_.cancel();

                // Print out some information about the reply packet.
                posix_time::ptime now = posix_time::microsec_clock::universal_time();
                std::cout << length - ipv4_hdr.header_length()
                << " bytes from " << ipv4_hdr.source_address()
                << ": icmp_seq=" << icmp_hdr.sequence_number()
                << ", ttl=" << ipv4_hdr.time_to_live()
                << ", time=" << (now - time_sent_).total_milliseconds() << " ms"
                << std::endl;
            }

            start_receive();
        }

        static unsigned short get_identifier()
        {
            #if defined(BOOST_ASIO_WINDOWS)
            return static_cast<unsigned short>(::GetCurrentProcessId());
            #else
            return static_cast<unsigned short>(::getpid());
            #endif
        }

        icmp::resolver resolver_;
        icmp::endpoint destination_;
        icmp::socket socket_;
        deadline_timer timer_;
        unsigned short sequence_number_;
        posix_time::ptime time_sent_;
        boost::asio::streambuf reply_buffer_;
        std::size_t num_replies_;
};
```

Thanks you by advance.
A C++ very-beginer

Edit :
Without the start_receive() in handle_receive the program just stop.

```
void displayEntry(string adrIP) 
{ 
    cout<<"Little try"; 
    pinger p(io_service, adrIP.c_str()); 
    io_service.run(); 
    cout << "\rThis line won't happen :(" << endl; 
} 

int main()
{ 
    string ipAdr = "192.168.1.1"; 

    while (1) 
    { 
        displayEntry(ipAdr); 
    } 
}
```

"Little try" will be displayed, but "This line won't happen :(" won't

Comment: Regardin the `:`, read a book! C++ doesn't come by osmosis, usually. (Google [base/member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list)).

Comment: @sehe Ok, I ever looked at that, but the problem is that I call this function in `main()` but don't go bacck there, the program just stop. For an example, in this code `void displayEntry(string adrIP)
{
 cout<<"Little try";
 pinger p(io_service, adrIP.c_str());
 io_service.run();
 cout << "\rThis line won't happen :(" << endl;
}

int main()
{
 string ipAdr = "192.168.1.1"; 
 while (1)
 {
  displayEntry(ipAdr);
 }
}` "Little try" will be written, but the lane "This line won't happen :(" doesn't. Any idea ? Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: Okay, I see now that your comment was complete (please edit your question next time, this is unreadable). I've updated my answer.

Comment: @NorthernLight "Without the start_receive() in handle_receive the program just stop.

" Really?If that's true, then why you say ""This line won't happen :(" won't" later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program keeps going because at the end of `handle_receive` it calls `start_receive` again, unconditionally.

**Update** To the comment: the code doesn't reach after

```
io_service.run();
```

because the IO service never runs out of work (new async operations are scheduled each time). Only when the process is interrupted/killed will it stop and in the absense of a signal handler for that your "This line won't happen" line won't get executed anymore.

Look at `signal_set` to handle e.g. Ctrl-C http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/signal_set.html

Comment: Then how to stop `io_service.run();`? Invoking `io_service.stop();` in another thread? Am I right?